# What's the Point of Project Management.SE?

Tags: discussion

I think the whole SE enterprise is getting a bit too fragmented.

Don't you think that Project Management should be merged with programmers SE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not at all.

Although most of the questions here are about software project management, good project management techniques can be applied across every field, including research projects. It's very clear that the Programmers (which is still a bad name, IMO) SE is about software development from the perspective of the engineer working on a software project, while the PM SE is from the perspective of a manager and is independent of the type of project.

Another way of looking at it is that the Programmers SE covers topics in the Software Engineering Body of Knowledge (SWEBOK) while PM SE covers topics in the Project Management Body of Knowledge (PMBOK). Although it's expected that a good software engineer has some understanding of basic PM concepts (and the PMBOK is cited within the SWEBOK as an additional resource), they are very different beasts.

Comment: I see; maybe you can explicitly mention this in FAQ and "About" Page.

Comment: +1 for SWEBOK vs. PMBOK comparison

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not.  The site is already getting too broad as it is with merging IT Management (assuming that is what will happen).

I would also say that Programmers SE does a good job in making sure the questions fall within their guidelines, and merging Project Management with Programming could harm Programmers SE as well as eliminate a place where good PM questions could be asked.

PM is still trying to learn to fly.  It will take some time for this community to effectively police itself.  Once it does, I hope to see this site have the same quality questions as Programmers SE, except with a focus on Project Management.

It's also important to point out that Construction Project Management, Engineering Project Management, Environmental Project Management, ${Insert_field_here} Project Management may all fit within the guidelines of Project Management SE, but would be strictly prohibited on a site specifically about programming.

Check out the [FAQ](https://pm.stackexchange.com/faq) for a more thorough description of the purpose of this site.

Comment: The site is getting too broad? That doesn't make sense. You mean maybe amazon.com should move different categories to different domains with different logins and tags and..

Comment: So you're suggesting we merge the entire SE network?